# How can I use proxies in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

When I try to use a proxy in firefox it doesn't work, the code doesn't give me any error, all works good but the ip doesn't change.

But when I do it with chrome it works.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "ipproxy"

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument ('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
firefox = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
firefox.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```